# Firebase Error: The project cannot be created because you have exceeded your allotted project quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

My firebase console account has four projects created, so I was trying to create another project but then I received this error **The operation has failed (Reason: The project cannot be created because you have exceeded your allotted project quota.)**

I looked for answers on Stackoverflow but did not get the solution, I have tried many times and the error is still popping up.

Please I need help